# Show only Errors and warnings in Powershell

Tags: powershell, output, pipeline

Noob asking for help here

I have few scrips written for users to run, i would like the users to see ONLY Error and warning output without all the success output.

Online search lead me to believe i need to present the piplines of Error and Warning, but nowhere i could find a way to implement getting only those two in a script, can some one please explain how do i implement in a script seeing only Error and warning?

For example the following part of the script shows the output below it, user experience is a lot of output which an error get lost in.

```
 $script1 = "sudo sed -i 's/'$hostn'/'$VMs_Name$i'/g' /etc/hosts"
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMs_Name$i -ScriptText $script1 -GuestUser root -GuestPassword xsignnet1 -ScriptType Bash
            
$script2 = "sudo sed -i 's/'$hostn'/'$VMs_Name$i'/g' /etc/hostname"
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMs_Name$i -ScriptText $script2 -GuestUser root -GuestPassword xsignnet1 -ScriptType Bash
```

---

```
VM           : testing_vm_1
ExitCode     : 0
ScriptOutput :
Uid          : /VIServer=vsphere.local\scripts@vcsa-st-vvol-67-2.lab.gdc.il.infinidat.com:443/VirtualMachine=VirtualMachine-vm-541/VMScriptResult=1665179762_0/
Length       : 0


VM           : testing_vm_1
ExitCode     : 0
ScriptOutput : sudo: unable to resolve host Ubuntu-Template: Resource temporarily unavailable

Uid          : /VIServer=vsphere.local\scripts@vcsa-st-vvol-67-2.lab.gdc.il.infinidat.com:443/VirtualMachine=VirtualMachine-vm-541/VMScriptResult=-942405014_0/
Length       : 79
```

Comment: Here is a really good guide how the diffrent steams works in PowerShell: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Assign the output of the `Invoke-VMScript` cmdlet to `$null`.
2. Pipe the output of the `Invoke-VMScript` cmdlet to the `Out-Null` cmdlet.

**Example:**

```
$null = Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMs_Name$i -ScriptText $script1 -GuestUser root -GuestPassword xsignnet1 -ScriptType Bash
# or:
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMs_Name$i -ScriptText $script1 -GuestUser root -GuestPassword xsignnet1 -ScriptType Bash | Out-Null
```

**Demonstration:**

```
function Verb-Noun
{
    "normal output, shouldn't be printed when pipe to Out-Null"

    Write-Warning "you should see me, I am a warning"
    Write-Error "you should see me, I am an error"
    
}

Verb-Noun | Out-Null
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @MartinBrandl  1) Isn't there a way to apply to the all script? - my script however basic consist of around 10s of commands, i would not want to manually add to each one of them if possible.


 2) Isn't $null & Out-Null send all types of piplines into null? i do wish to see Errors and Warnings as i mentioned

Comment: You should do that for every line where you don't want to see the output. Like in your example you see the response of the Invoke-VMScript which you don't want, so you have to pipe it to Out-Null. You will see Errors since they are sent to the error stream